# React-native carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hello how can I make the upward sliding version of the image in the picture
Help me please

[This Image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e566b0b4466fd8345be80d01e02b5138745508f425b9be5c4864fe8277455886/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f46784d67356d642e676966)

Answer (score 0):

try using `Flatlist`, set  `pagingEnabled={true}` and `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}` set `decelerationRate="normal"`. If you style your items in the list properly, this should work.